# Get the size of a directory and store it into variable

Tags: bash, ssh

I try to run a command from a server A to get the size of a directory located on server B.

I got a blank result using this command:

```
ssh root@remoteIP -t "size=$(du -hs /var/www/somesite.com/dir1/dir2/uploads/ |
                             awk '{print $2}'); echo ${size} ; bash --login"
```

Comment: if you want to make calculation then don't use the `-h` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested this locally with:
`size=$(ssh xxx@yyy "du -hs ./.config | cut -f 1") ; echo $size`

and got the correct output in my terminal:

```
size=$(ssh xxx@yyy "du -hs ./.config | cut -f 1") ; echo $size
8.0K
```

Comment: I would like to have the size not the directory path. To be ablse to make any calculation with the variable

Comment: If you adapt my example to your use-case, you will see, that the result is the size of the folder in KB, MB, etc. from the remote host.

Comment: You could make an example of the output of `du -h /dir` to make an example of why  `awk {print $1}`.

Comment: @BulletBob following your exemple gives an output that looks like that 

55692 /var/www/somesite.com/dir1/dir2/uploads/

and i would like 55692 only

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Misread my output for some reason. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: That’s I was looking for thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The line you want to pass to your `SSH` command is:

```
size=$(du -hs /some/dir | awk '{print $1}'; echo ${size} ; bash --login
```

You have to **protect** some **characters** of this line from begin **intepreted**: **`$`** and **`'`**.

- A good way to **protect `$`** is to **use simple quotes** `'`, because double quotes `"` won't make it:

  ```
  'blah blah "blah blah" blah' # sounds easy
  ```
- **Protecting simple quotes** is a little trickier if you use simple quotes to surround your line: a way is to put before the simple quote a closing simple quote (yes), then **surround** the simple quote with **double quotes** `"` and eventually reopen with a simple quote:

  ```
  'blah blah '"'"'blah blah'"'"' blah' # mmh well
  ```

Also what you wanted is to print the **first** field with `awk`, not the second one. So `print $1`, not `print $2`.

Here is your well-protected line:

```
ssh root@remoteIP -t 'size=$(du -hs /some/dir | awk '"'"'{print $1}'"'"')
                      echo ${size} ; bash --login'
```